# Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker within modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am currently using the Twitter Bootstrap framework, and when using the modal windows I cannot get over js elements to work like datepicker or validation, though chosen and uniform render correctly. please see my modal window below:

```
  <div class="modal hide in" id="newMember" style="display: block; " aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
          <h3>New Member Form</h3>
        </div>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/players" class="form-horizontal" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="KdL6cc2Vb53qeMY+PpBUS70myT4HX1uWofMUBolLea8="></div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_role">Role</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <select id="user_role" name="user[role]" style="display: none; " class="chzn-done"><option value="">Select member role</option>
                  <option value="1">Player</option>
                  <option value="2">Coach</option>
                  <option value="3">Parent</option>
                  <option value="4">Manager</option>
                  <option value="5">Non-player</option></select><div id="user_role_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 222px; "><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single"><span>Select member role</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 220px; top: 0px; "><div class="chzn-search" style=""><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 212px; "></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="user_role_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">Select member role</li><li id="user_role_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Player</li><li id="user_role_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Coach</li><li id="user_role_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">Parent</li><li id="user_role_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">Manager</li><li id="user_role_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">Non-player</li></ul></div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_full_name">Full name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" placeholder="First Name" size="30" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_last_name">Last name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" placeholder="Last Name" size="30" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email Address" size="30" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_date_of_birth">Date of birth</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="user_dob" name="user[dob]" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly="readonly" size="30" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_gender">Gender</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <select id="user_gender" name="user[gender]" style="display: none; " class="chzn-done"><option value="">Select gender</option>
                  <option value="Male">Male</option>
                  <option value="Female">Female</option></select><div id="user_gender_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 222px; "><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single"><span>Select gender</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 220px; top: 0px; "><div class="chzn-search" style=""><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 212px; "></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="user_gender_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">Select gender</li><li id="user_gender_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Male</li><li id="user_gender_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Female</li></ul></div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_team">Team</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <select id="user_team_id" name="user[team_id]" style="display: none; " class="chzn-done"><option value="">None</option>
                  <option value="4">Metro 3 East</option>
                  <option value="1">State League 3</option>
                  <option value="2">State League 4</option>
                  <option value="3">Metro 3 South</option>
                  <option value="5">Pennant E</option>
                  <option value="6">Under 9 White</option>
                  <option value="7">Under 9 Navy</option>
                  <option value="8">Under 13 Pennant South East</option>
                  <option value="9">Under 17 Pennant South East</option>
                  <option value="10">Under 15 South (1)</option>
                  <option value="11">Under 11 Pennant South East</option>
                  <option value="12">Under 11 South</option></select><div id="user_team_id_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 222px; "><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single"><span>None</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 220px; top: 0px; "><div class="chzn-search" style=""><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 212px; "></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">None</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Metro 3 East</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">State League 3</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">State League 4</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">Metro 3 South</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">Pennant E</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">Under 9 White</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">Under 9 Navy</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">Under 13 Pennant South East</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_9" class="active-result" style="">Under 17 Pennant South East</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_10" class="active-result" style="">Under 15 South (1)</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_11" class="active-result" style="">Under 11 Pennant South East</li><li id="user_team_id_chzn_o_12" class="active-result" style="">Under 11 South</li></ul></div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_mobile">Mobile</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input id="user_mobile" maxlength="10" name="user[mobile]" placeholder="i.e 0421813529" size="10" type="tel">
                  <span class="help-block">
                    <input name="user[private_mobile]" type="hidden" value="0"><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_private_mobile"><span><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_private_mobile"><span><input id="user_private_mobile" name="user[private_mobile]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div></span></div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tip-bottom" data-original-title="Normally, all members of the team can see this information. If you don't want teammates to see this information, just click this checkbox. (Note: Team managers will always see this information.)">Private</a>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_manager_access">Manager access</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input name="user[manager]" type="hidden" value="0"><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_manager"><span><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_manager"><span><input id="user_manager" name="user[manager]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_admin_access">Admin access</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input name="user[admin]" type="hidden" value="0"><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_admin"><span><div class="checker" id="uniform-user_admin"><span><input id="user_admin" name="user[admin]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="opacity: 0; "></span></div></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="pull-right">
              <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create User">
              <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you put your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It will make it easier for people to test it.

Comment: Have not had any problem getting these various JQuery plugins and JavaScript frameworks working together: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/xekuW/9/

Comment: @Sara here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h7cMa/

Comment: @mccannf after doing a bit of research into my issue it appears the css is causing the issue. when the window is loaded the z-index i think it is, is not allowing the tooltips or datepicker to be displayed

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane, I recommend you look at your bootstrap CSS and JS. Your modal is being set at a very high z-index value (99999). Just compare my jsfiddle above with yours.

Comment: @mccannf thanks you made it easy for me to find the issue which was in a second declaration

Answer (score 244, accepted):

add z-index above 1051 in  class datepicker

add something like this in page or css

```
<style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: It works however if I close the modal and open again then it throws an error.

Comment: It's been long time and I have already forgotten about it. Sorry!

Comment: @Sujaysreedhar just question: why is index 1151? I have changed it to 1000000 then it still worked but  this time it dispayed just additional  left top corner when the script runs

Comment: It dose not matter as long as its above 1150, since the modal window's z-index is 1150.. z-index determines which layer to show on top so as long as its above in ur case  1000000 it will work

Comment: If using bootstrap-datetimepicker.js the correct selector is `.ui-datepicker`

Answer (score 60):

for me it only worked with !important in css

```
.datepicker {z-index: 1151 !important;}
```

Comment: It only works for me with !important if added into the css file. However, if you put the style directly into the head of the page it seems to work fine without adding !important but this isn't great if the datepicker is going to be used across different pages.

Comment: Perfect! I added it in datepicker.css and works like a charm

Answer (score 12):

I use:

```
body.modal-open .datepicker {
    z-index: 1200 !important;
}
```

This way: if the modal **isn't** open, and you want the datepicker to be at the normal z-index (in my case I needed it to be under the menu drop-down, which has a z-index of 1000), it works.

If the modal **is** open, the datepicker needs to be over the modal z-index (1040 or 1050), so use the `body.modal-open` selector.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1

Answer (score 8):

According to http://www.daterangepicker.com/ (options)

```
$('#dispatch_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
     // prepare datepicker
     $('.form_datepicker').daterangepicker({
          singleDatePicker: true,
          showDropdowns: true,
          parentEl: '#dispatch_modal'   
     });
});
```

`

parentEl solved my problem...

Answer (score 7):

Add z-indez in class ui-datepicker

```
<style>
    .ui-datepicker{ z-index:1151 !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

As [mccannf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736297/mccannf) said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window/13009680#comment17631568_12978254):

I recommend you look at your bootstrap CSS and JS. Your modal is being set at a very high z-index value (99999). Just compare my jsfiddle above with yours

Answer (score 4):

Try with this piece of code.

`.ui-datepicker{ z-index:1151 !important; }`

will solve the problem when you are using **bootstrap V3**

Comment: `.ui-datepicker` worked for me where `.datepicker` did not.

Answer (score 3):

I think is better to change the logical function in the plugin. Around row 552 i change this:

```
            var zIndex = parseInt(this.element.parents().filter(function(){
                return $(this).css('z-index') !== 'auto';
            }).first().css('z-index'))+10;
```

into this:

```
            var zIndex = parseInt(this.element.parents().filter(function(){
                return $(this).css('z-index') !== 'auto';
            }).first().css('z-index')) + 10 * 1000; //think is enought
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, because i scrolled bottom. Datepicker had wrong top position in fixed. I just use it now like:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

and its working fine now.

Comment: It worked for me as a temporary solution. Thank you very much. But I'd like to find a final solution to make my datepicker show up correctly, no matter the scroll position is. I'll try to find it later on. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

can you change in your css file `bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css`

from

```
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.open {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.open {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:1151;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if You  use bootstrap V3 try this.

```
    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget 
    {
        z-index: 1200   !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#effective_to').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function() { 
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('datepicker');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.datepicker {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
    display: block;
}
```

This works form me. Even though I called model via ajax

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3.x and Ace Template [wrapbootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR)

Datepicker and Timepicker inside a Modal

```
<style>
    body.modal-open .datepicker {
        z-index: 1050 !important;
    }
    body.modal-open .bootstrap-timepicker-widget {
        z-index: 1050 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solutions worked perfectly for me to render the datepicker on top of bootstrap modal.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmpgtuwy/654/

HTML

```
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
Some content goes here<br />
Some more content.
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">

<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="input-group date" id="dtp">
<input type="text" class="form-control" />  
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#dtp').datetimepicker({
format: 'MMM D, YYYY',
widgetParent: 'body'});


$('#dtp').on('dp.show', function() {
      var datepicker = $('body').find('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget:last');
      if (datepicker.hasClass('bottom')) {
        var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var left = $(this).offset().left;
        datepicker.css({
          'top': top + 'px',
          'bottom': 'auto',
          'left': left + 'px'
        });
      }
      else if (datepicker.hasClass('top')) {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - datepicker.outerHeight();
        var left = $(this).offset().left;
        datepicker.css({
          'top': top + 'px',
          'bottom': 'auto',
          'left': left + 'px'
        });
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;}
body {
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is for bootstrap-datetimepicker but still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change z-index value for `.modal` and `.modal-backdrop` less than `.datepicker` z-index value.

Answer (score 0):

For BootsTrap Calender use this

/*The Calender Index CSS*/

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
   z-index:99999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use this code it works for me.
by the way it came from this site
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/464
.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('show', function () {
                var modal = $('#datepicker').closest('.modal');
                var datePicker = $('body').find('.datepicker');
                if (!modal.length) {
                    $(datePicker).css('z-index', 'auto');
                    return;
                }
                var zIndexModal = $(modal).css('z-index');
                $(datePicker).css('z-index', zIndexModal + 1);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw.
Necro but still.

for  `<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I needed

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-timepicker-container {z-index: 1151 !important;}
</style>
```

in the HEAD of the doc for it to accept the override

I tried most every other solution on here before resorting to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// re initialze datepicker
$(".bootstrap-datepicker").bsdatepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $(this).bsdatepicker('hide');
});
//
$(".dropdown-menu").css({'z-index':'1100'});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

let me help you,

you can to update your bootstrap.min.css

in class dropdown-menu you can to change z-index value into 2000

so datepicker will show up

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your datapicker JavaScript code inside

```
function pageLoad() {}
```