# Getting jquery event to fire for element in ajax loaded partial view (bootstrap modal form)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to figure out the correct approach for initializing jquery events referencing partial view elements loaded via ajax. Specifically I'm trying to use bootstrap-datepicker.js in a in a bootstrap modal form.

Background: Had a functioning page with datepicker working. Project for today was to convert that form to a bootstrap modal. A lot of what I did came from [MVC 4 Edit modal form using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011151/mvc-4-edit-modal-form-using-bootstrap/16011752#16011752)

All that is working fine. Since I am now loading the partial view via ajax, datepicker doesn't work. I understand the problem, I just don't know the solution. Any advice appreciated.

**Calling view has**

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="addclassroom">
    <div id="classroom-container"></div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addclassbtn').click(function () {
        var url = "/Quiz/AddClassroom?quizId=@ViewBag.quizid"; 
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#classroom-container').html(data);
            $('#addclassroom').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult AddClassroom(int quizId)
{
    var classroom = ...
    return PartialView("_AddClassroom",classroom);
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddClassroom", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post,
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        //InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        UpdateTargetId = "addclassroom"
                    }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal-body">
            <fieldset class="QuizDisplayFields">
                *fields...etc*
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new {@class="datefield" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
                *more fields...*
                <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }

<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker();
    });
   </script>
   <script>
       $(function ($) {
           $("#StartDate").on("click").datepicker();
       });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready` won't work in a partial. It is only executed when the page is loaded initially.

So you need to shift those scripts, inside the partial, to the callback function of your ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's what I gathered, but nothing I tried had worked. The answer turned out to be a combination of that AND this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window
For reasons I don't really understand I had to add 
.datepicker{z-index:1151;} to my css.

Comment: Hmm strange. The z-index fix looks like the datepicker was hiding behind the modal. Bootstrap modal has a z-index of 1050 hence datepicker is given a higher z-index value.