# Set datepicker to an element after being created

Tags: jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog

I want to set an input field a datepicker inside a modal bootstrap form, I created that form as follows:

```
$('<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
```

I tried assign it to a var for access and set up but nothing changes...

```
var self = $('<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
self.find(".input-date").datepicker();
```

Any ideas?

Regards!

**edit with the code of data**

```
<form class ="form" method="POST" action="{{ request.path }}">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h3>Editar Empleado</h3>
</div>              

    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>
                <label for="input-date">Date:</label>
                <input class="input-date" type="text" />
            </p>                
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrar btn">Cerrar</a>
        <input type="submit" class="guardar btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nobody will have any idea unless you post the generated HTML. Your selector `input-date` looks bogus though - check you're actually matching anything with it

Comment: Yes, I forgot the 'dot' selector for classes, I'm going to edit with the form data that is appended with the myModal

Comment: Does the modal even show? I don't think it does, because it looks like you're not actually appending the generated HTML to the DOM. Can you post the relevant JS as well?

Comment: Well... the problem was involved with the z-index of the datepicker... I solved following the instructions in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window