# Jquery Calendar appears below the Popup in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, calendar

I am using jquery calendar and I am using it on a popup window. It appears below the popup in chrome and works fine for firefox. Please check the screen shots. How can I fix this?

[image: This is Firefox]

[image: Issue in Chrome]

Comment: The First Screen is of Firefox which is ok and second one is from Chrome and has the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113178/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working-in-chrome