# How can I put Bootstrap inline datepicker in bootstrap Modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I want to integrate bootstrap datepicker to bootstrap modal body, this is my code but it didnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker('show');

});

</script>

</head>

<body >

<div id="calendarPopup" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="stack-header"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" >

 <div class="datepicker" data-date="" style="display:block!important;"></div>


 </div>

</div>

<script>

$('#calendarPopup').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
 $('#calendarPopup').modal('show');

</script>

</body>
```

---

It shows the modal without the datepicker, is there any solution?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window

Comment: It didn't work for me...

Comment: can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Because i dont use input field, i display the datepicker directly after opening the modal window.

Comment: here the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wiss90/yxxysyhh/

Comment: you did not include datepicker.js in it

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

You need an embedded datepicker like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2d5L2xcc/8/)

---

You need `bootstrap-datepicker.js` and also datepicker works on `input` elements.

This code snippet will make sure that datepicker will work anywhere in the HTML page

```
$('body')
    .on('click', '.datepicker', function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
})
    .on('focus', '.datepicker', function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d5L2xcc/4/)

Comment: I made it work like that before , but as i told , i want to display the datepicker directly to the modal without any text input.

Comment: you can hide the input text because datepicker cannot be applied to anything apart from input. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2d5L2xcc/6/

Comment: but the problem that the modal won't feet dynamically the datepicker.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You need an embed datepicker like this http://jsfiddle.net/2d5L2xcc/8/

Comment: i got this 'error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined'. I will post my final code to see the error in it and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/jquery-ui2.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/calendar.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabbedwindow.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabdrop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/noselection.css">  

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"> 

   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap-tabdrop.js"></script>

 <script src="js/jquery.doubletap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
$(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {
  // $('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
});

$('.datepicker').on("hide", function(event) {



});

$('div.datepicker.dropdown-menu').css('display:block !important;');
});

</script>

</head>

<body >





<div id="calendarPopup" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" onclick="closeBox();" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="stack-header"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" >

<div id="datepicker" data-date="12/03/2012"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input" />

 </div>

</div>

<script>

$('#calendarPopup').modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    $("#calendarPopup .modal-body").html();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").on("changeDate", function (event) {
        $("#my_hidden_input").val(
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('getFormattedDate'))
    });



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function closeBox() {

tabbedWindowHTML = '<ul id="tabs_list" class="nav nav-tabs" style="flex: 0 0 auto">';

}

   Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all have all the scripts in one single <script> tag. 
And it seems to be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2d5L2xcc/9/ Please show the error that you see