# jQuery UI DatePicker not appearing inside Bootbox modal loaded through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, bootbox

I need to dynamically load a form into a Bootbox modal window. I'm loading the form through Ajax. In the form is a jQuery UI datepicker field.

Using the browser's debugger, when the form is loaded through Ajax, I can see the datepicker element added to the DOM. But, clicking the field doesn't do anything. The calendar doesn't appear, and more importantly, the datepicker DOM element doesn't change like it does when I load a datepicker field directly on the page.

Here's my Ajax call from the index page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    timeout: "100000",
    url: "/cfc/site_functions.cfc",
    beforeSend: function (){ 
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Loading...",
            title: modal_title,
            onEscape:false,
            backdrop:true,
            closeButton:true,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": {}
            }
        });
    },
    data: {
        method: "buildMyForm"
    },
    success: function(objResponse){
        $(".bootbox-body").html(objResponse);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $(".bootbox-body").html("Error loading form.");
    }
});
```

Here's the Coldfusion function being called by the Ajax call which builds the form and initializes the datepicker field:

```
<cffunction name="buildMyForm" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="plain">

    <cfsavecontent variable="local.buildMyForm">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $("#date_posted").datepicker({
                    showAnim: "slide"
                });
            });
        </script>

        <cfoutput>

            <form method="post" id="edit_form" name="edit_form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date_posted" class="required">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_posted" name="date_posted" required autocomplete="off">
                </div>

            </form>

        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfreturn local.buildMyForm>
</cffunction>
```

Any thoughts why the datepicker element would initialize, but then not work when you click the date field?  There's a similar question but it's solution was to update the CSS because the datepicker calendar was showing with a lower z-index than the Bootbox modal. But, in my case, the datepicker element isn't being populated at all when you click the date field, so it's not just a matter of it being hidden.

Comment: Maybe try to move the `.datepicker()` call inside the success function just after the `.html()`, instead of within the ColdFusion function.The `$(document).ready(function(e) {});` must not be triggered due to the ajax load.

Comment: No luck. I first deleted it from the function and refreshed. Then I tried opening the form in the modal and the datepicker element never appeared in the DOM - just as expected.  Then I added the `datepicker()` call after the `.html()` and again, the datepicker element is initialized and appears in the DOM, but clicking the field does nothing.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console  ?

Comment: No, there are no errors.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a Fiddle/Codepen ? I tried, but everything works fine : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaLBwp

Comment: I can't because it's loading the form through ajax from another page.  I tried your solution locally, creating the `simulatedResponse` var to hold the form html, and it worked locally.  So it's something to do with the form being loaded through ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker within modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window)

Comment: @JamesAMohler - This was not a duplicate. That issue was solved by setting the datepicker's z-index. That was one of the first things I tried as I mentioned in my question. In this case, the datepicker was initializing, but not opening when the date field was clicked. My solution was to wait to initialize and show the datepicker until after the date field was clicked for the first time, rather than initializing the field on-ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @EdenSource for helping narrow down the problem.

It seems there may have been some competition on when the datepicker code was firing.  I updated the javascript in the CFC (the code that was being called by the ajax function to build the form) and it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#date_posted").on("focus",function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass("hasDatepicker")){
                $(this).datepicker({
                    showAnim: "slide"
                });
                $(this).addClass("hasDatepicker");
                $(this).datepicker("show");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```