# DatePicker in Modal

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I have add a date in modal dialog in my php application.When i click the control, the calendar is showing in left corner of the page and also even after selecting the date,when i clicking somewhere the calendar does not get closed.
My code:

```
<div class="modal" id="apply_Compensation_Leave" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"> 
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><li class="fa fa-times"/></button>
        <h3 style="font-size: 17px;">Apply Leave</h3>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="Compensation_Leave" >
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Leave Dates</label>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="from">From</label>
            <div class="input-group date" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">               
                <input type='text' id="startdate" class="form-control" name="startdate" ></input>
                <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="to">To</label>
            <div class="input-group date" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">   
                <input id="enddate" type="text" class="form-control" name="enddate" ></input>
                <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="leave_status">Reason</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea id="leave_reason" class="form-control" name="leave_reason" maxlength="500"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">      
            <button onclick="" class="btn">Apply Leaves</button>
            <button onclick="modJs.showLeaveView();return false;" class="btn">Back</button>     
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#startdate,#enddate').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

if i change my script like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#startdate,#enddate').datetimepicker({ z-index: 9999 !important;});
            });
        </script>
```

Calendar is not appearing,just it shows the all date as combo box in the text box itself in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> have you included this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker within modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window)

Answer (score 0):

I add style in php page as below,now its working.

```
        <style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>
```

i got this solution from [Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker within modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window)
Previosuly i tried in inside javascript,thats why it didnt work.