# AngularJS - datepicker coming up behind modal

Tags: angularjs, html, datepicker

More than a question, this is a sharing of something I recently had to deal with and took me several hours to put it in the right way.

I was using the datepicker in a modal window, when I clicked the control, the calendar came up but behind the modal, let's say between the parent window and the modal

After looking all over the place, I could fix by simply change an attribute in the markup:
   datepicker-append-to-body:
     true  --> makes the calendar to show behind the modal;
     false --> the calendar is shown in the right place, within the modal;

This is my markup as an example:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text"
    class="form-control input-sm"
    ng-model="scheduleDates.startDate"
    jquery-maskedinput
    data-mask="99/99/9999"
    data-mask-placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
    uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
    datepicker-append-to-body="false"
    is-open="datePicker.startDateIsOpen"
    close-text="Close"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button 
       type="button" 
       class="btn btn-sm btn-default" 
       ng-click="openStartDatePicker()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker within modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window)

Answer (score 0):

Set the datepicker-append-to-body attribute to false to display the calendar just in the modal (in front of the modal)